# How, in Py3k, do I have a signal handler prevent the default action of a signal?

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, signals

In [How can I add signal handlers to a shell written in Py3k/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318447/how-can-i-add-signal-handlers-to-a-shell-written-in-py3k-python), I had signal handlers that seemed to act and then let the default action pass through. For a concrete instance, if I hit control-Z, it would display the message specified by the signal handler, and then (what was unwanted) continue through to suspend the process.

How (if it is possible) do I display a message and then otherwise ignore a signal?

Comment: (Setting a SIG_IGN handler for control-Z didn't seem to work.)

Answer (score 0):

Your key-presses might raising `SIGSTOP` rather than `SIGSTP`. 
In your terminal run `stty -a` to determine the exact signal which is assigned to `ctrl+z`.

According to wikipedia (and probably man pages too) [`SIGSTP` and `SIGSTOP` are different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals).
`SIGSTP` is sent to the process, and thus can be intercepted, whereas `SIGSTOP` is picked up by the OS and thus cannot be intercepted.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-Z is not a signal, it's a key combination. On Windows, CTRL-Z will send an [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) which also is not a signal, so I assume you mean on Unix, as most Unix shells will send a signal on CTRL-Z, namely the SIGTSTP signal.

Changing the handler for SIGTSTP works fine:

```
>>> import signal
>>> def handler(signum, frame):
...    print(signum, frame, "yay!")
... 
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)
0
<Here I press CTRL-Z>
>>> 20 None yay!
```